# ModX Revo + UniSender отправка сообщений из доп. полей

Tags: modx

Имеется несколько сайтов, с разными версиями ModX, возьмем за основу 
MODX Revolution 2.3.3

Был установлен плагин  UniSender Integration 1.7.4-pl,
который осуществляет интеграцию ModX и системы рассылки сообщений UniSender.
Плагин настроен, все работает, но возникла загвоздка с передачей изображений (их ссылок) из доп. полей.

к примеру, вот код для вставки изображения в чанке рассылки:

```
<tr><td>[[getImageList? &tvname=`unisender_image`&tpl=`@CODE:[[+images]]`]]</td></tr>
```

также пробовали вставлять ссылки и с помощью `[[*images]] [[+images]]` и через `getResourseList`.

в данном коде, который приведен выше, вылетает ошибка при сохранении документа:

```
Ошибка
/var/www/html/*адрес_сайта*/core/components/gallery/elements/tv/output/
```

Вот чанк полностью:

```
<tr><td align="center" valign="top"><img height="121" src="[[++logo]]" width="234"></td></tr>
<tr><td>[[getImageList? &tvname=`unisender_image`&tpl=`@CODE:[[+images]]`]]</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" ><h3 data-mce-style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0.4rem 0px; text-align: center; color: #5f3b0a; font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fcf8f4;" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0.4rem 0px;text-align: center;color: #5f3b0a;font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;background-color: #fcf8f4;"><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">[[+pagetitle]]</span></h3></td></tr>
<tr><td> [[+introtext]]</td></tr>
```

Comment: '[2016-07-19 14:28:49] (WARN @ /var/www/html/*/core/model/modx/modparser.class.php : 493) PHP notice: Trying to get property of non-object
'[2016-07-19 14:28:49] (WARN @ /connectors/index.php) `42` was requested but no alias was located.
'[2016-07-19 14:28:49] (DEBUG @ /connectors/index.php) Message created:54336138

Comment: Эти ошибки вообще ничего не дают без указания того что находится в той строчке где `Trying to get property of non-object`. И желательно хотябы небольшого расследования какие значения переменных привели к этому результату.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тем данным что написаны, есть два места в которых может возникнуть ошибка:

1. Не указан айдишник документа с которого брать картинку:

   ```
   &docid=`[[+id]]`
   ```
2. Конструкцию `@CODE:[[+images]]` лучше переделать в чанк отдельный.

Comment: не помогло.. все такая же ошибка.